# Select everything and a sum?

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
select *, sum(hrs.WPTOTT) as "Hours"
  from mstwmlt 
 inner join MSTWMPRD hrs
    ON hrs.WPOPID  = wtopid and hrs.WPTRAN = wtttyp 
       and (wttdte BETWEEN hrs.WPSDTE AND hrs.WPEDTE)
 where (wtwh = ? OR ? = '*ALL') 
   AND (wtopid = ? OR ? = '*ALL') 
   AND (wtttyp = ? OR ? = '*ALL')  
   and ((wtco|| '/' || wtdiv) = ?)
 order by wttdte, wtopid, wtttme, wtttyp
```

I need to select everything and the sum, is there a way to do it without writing a long select query for each individual field?

Comment: What database server do you use? That might change the options you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUM` being an aggregate function cannot be applied and selected along with other columns without using a `GROUP BY` on those columns.

Answer (score 0):

In almost any database other than MySQL, you can do something like:

```
with t as (
    select *
      from mstwmlt 
     inner join MSTWMPRD hrs
        ON hrs.WPOPID  = wtopid and hrs.WPTRAN = wtttyp 
           and (wttdte BETWEEN hrs.WPSDTE AND hrs.WPEDTE)
     where (wtwh = ? OR ? = '*ALL') 
       AND (wtopid = ? OR ? = '*ALL') 
       AND (wtttyp = ? OR ? = '*ALL')  
       and ((wtco|| '/' || wtdiv) = ?)
    )
 select t.*,
        (select sum(wpptott) from t) as Hours 
 from t
 order by wttdte, wtopid, wtttme, wtttyp
```

Unfortunately, I suspect you are using MySQL (because it is the only engine where your query would not generate a compile-time error, due to the presence of the `SUM` without a `GROUP BY` clause).  In this case, you have basically three reasonable options:

1. Duplicate the original query to get the sum.  Do this within the correlated subquery or in the FROM clause.
2. Use ROLLUP to get the sum on another row.
3. Do the summation at the application layer, outside the database.